# ArcObjects VB.NET forms in ArcMap 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, vb.net

I am trying to create a basic form using ArcObjects (VB.NET) to view in ArcMap 10.0. I have created the form using the designer but can't view it in ArcMap. I have created a button that will call the form and show it using `form.show()` method but seems it does nothing when I click it.

How can I show GUI forms in ArcMap? I thought by creating a separate button to call the form will work?

Form code:

```
Public Class ArcGISForm

    Public Sub New(ByVal hook As Object)
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.Hook = hook
    End Sub

    Private m_hook As Object

    Public Property Hook() As Object
    Get
      Return m_hook
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
      m_hook = value
    End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>

    '''creating and disposing the user interface class for the dockable window.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class AddinImpl
        Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.DockableWindow

        Private m_windowUI As ArcGISForm

        Protected Overrides Function OnCreateChild() As System.IntPtr
          m_windowUI = New ArcGISForm(Me.Hook)
          Return m_windowUI.Handle
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal Param As Boolean)
          If m_windowUI IsNot Nothing Then
            m_windowUI.Dispose(Param)
          End If

          MyBase.Dispose(Param)
        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Sub ArcGISForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm2 As New ArcMapAddin2.ArcGISForm(Me.Hook)
        frm2.Hide()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is how I am trying to call the form, from a button.

```
Public Class showform
Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
        Dim frm As New ArcMapAddin2.ArcGISForm(Me.Hook)
        frm.Show()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any ideas how I can open the form from the button? Or should I follow a different method?

UPDATE:

I have tried the following and still doesn't work:

```
Dim oForm As ArcGISForm
oForm = New ArcGISForm(Me.Hook)
oForm.ShowDialog()
oForm = Nothing
```

All it does is close ArcMap down. When I click the button.

Comment: try ShowDialog method. perhaps your form is hidden or beneath the ArcMap's form. I did not reviewed the whole code in detail, but do a simple experiment. Create a brand new form, without anything and try to do a showdialog on it. It should work.

Comment: Hi @user65266 Seems like you misplaced your password. Maybe you want to [join these two accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Hi .not sure how that happened. I fixed the issue by using VB standard form template rather than the ESRI Arcobjects one.

Comment: I think my accounts are merged now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. As long as i didnt use the ESRI ArcMap Addin **form** template it was ok. With ArcMap addin forms it always gives an error about using Hooks. When you call the form must have a hook variable passed through it or something. Didnt quite understand it. But using the standard VB.net form was ok.

```
Dim oform As New ArcMapAddin2.Form2()
oform.ShowDialog()
oform = Nothing
```

As long as you dont add any Hooks in the form then the above code should work if you need to call the form from a button in Arcmap.